# VBA - adapting cell ranges in workbook for email send out

Tags: vba, excel, outlook, range

I'm currently working on a piece of code where I'm sending out a daily email which has the excel file included as an attachment, as well as having the active worksheet embedded into the body of the email. I've been asked to find out whether its possible to have the embedded component of the VBA adapt to include new cell ranges.

So, for example. On one worksheet it will contain data for that day's trading activity. If I want to add Day 2's trading data on to the same worksheet and have only that section embedded into the email, is it possible without editing the cell ranges every time in VBA?

I've attached my code below:

```
Sub Mail_Sheet_Outlook_Body()

    Dim rng As Range
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object

    With Application
        .EnableEvents = False
        .ScreenUpdating = False
    End With

    Set rng = Nothing
    Set rng = ActiveSheet.UsedRange
    'You can also use a sheet name
    'Set rng = Sheets("YourSheet").UsedRange

    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

    On Error Resume Next
    With OutMail
        .to = "recipient@test.com"
        .CC = ""
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = "Trades Today" & Date
        .HTMLBody = RangetoHTML(rng)
        .Attachments.Add ActiveWorkbook.FullName
        .Send                                    'or use .Display
    End With
    On Error GoTo 0

    With Application
        .EnableEvents = True
        .ScreenUpdating = True
    End With

    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing
End Sub

Function RangetoHTML(rng As Range)

    Dim fso As Object
    Dim ts As Object
    Dim TempFile As String
    Dim TempWB As Workbook

    TempFile = Environ$("temp") & "\" & Format(Now, "dd-mm-yy h-mm-ss") & ".htm"
    rng.Copy
    Set TempWB = Workbooks.Add(1)
    With TempWB.Sheets(1)
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=8
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, , False, False
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats, , False, False
        .Cells(1).Select
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        On Error Resume Next
        .DrawingObjects.Visible = True
        .DrawingObjects.Delete
        On Error GoTo 0
    End With

    'Publish the sheet to a htm file
    With TempWB.PublishObjects.Add( _
         SourceType:=xlSourceRange, _
         Filename:=TempFile, _
         Sheet:=TempWB.Sheets(1).Name, _
         Source:=TempWB.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Address, _
         HtmlType:=xlHtmlStatic)
        .Publish (True)
    End With

    'Read all data from the htm file into RangetoHTML
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set ts = fso.GetFile(TempFile).OpenAsTextStream(1, -2)
    RangetoHTML = ts.readall
    ts.Close
    RangetoHTML = Replace(RangetoHTML, "align=center x:publishsource=", _
                          "align=left x:publishsource=")

    'Close TempWB
    TempWB.Close savechanges:=False

    'Delete the htm file we used in this function
    Kill TempFile

    Set ts = Nothing
    Set fso = Nothing
    Set TempWB = Nothing

End Function
```

Any advice on this would be appreciated.

Comment: Is there an obvious way that you can tell one day's data from the next?

Comment: Because you can easily do this by changing `Set rng = ActiveSheet.UsedRange` to be a little smarter in the way it grabs the data. If, for example you have a date column in each day's data, it could be set to only copy today's or yesterday's data

Comment: I can add a date column into the workbook in order to do that. How would I need to change the code in order to do that?

Comment: thanks @Marcucciboy2

Answer (score 0):

My answer might seem a bit specific but I think that from it you can at least get the idea that I'm going for.

---

Here's what I'm considering the 'master' sheet. In this example, it hasn't been updated since yesterday (hence the date being `9/12/2018`).

[image: Master1]

Here is the worksheet with today's data:

[image]

The following script will take today's data, add a `"Date"` column to it, and fill in today's date for all of those rows. Then it will copy the data from the 'today' sheet over to the 'master' sheet at the top of the list.

```
Sub Data_Copy()

    Dim ws1 As Worksheet
    Set ws1 = ActiveSheet           'adjust as necessary

    Dim ws2 As Worksheet
    Set ws2 = sheets(ws1.index + 1) 'adjust as necessary

    Dim lastRow As Long
    lastRow = ws2.Range("A" & rows.count).End(xlUp).row

    If ws2.Range("A1").Value2 <> "Date" Then
        ws2.Columns(1).Insert Shift:=xlRight
        ws2.Range("A1").Value2 = "Date"

        ws2.Range("A2:A" & lastRow).value = Date
    End If

    ws2.rows("2:" & lastRow).copy
    ws1.rows(2).Insert Shift:=xlDown
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub
```

Data in the 'today' sheet after the previous script added the `"Date"` column:

[image]

And here's that 'master' sheet after today's data was inserted into it:

[image]

---

Finally, here is the updated `Mail_Sheet_Outlook_Body` sub so that grabs only the data with today's date from the `ActiveSheet` (which I was previously referring to as the 'master').

Now it works down column `A` and gets the row number when it does not find that cell to have today's date in it. Then it sets `rng` to go from `"A1"` over to the last column in the `UsedRange` and down to the last row that had today's date.

```
Sub Mail_Sheet_Outlook_Body()

    ...

    With Application
        .EnableEvents = False
        .ScreenUpdating = False
    End With


    'gets last row with today's date
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 2 To Range("A" & rows.count).End(xlUp).row
        If CDate(Range("A" & i).value) <> Date Then
            Exit For
        End If
    Next i

    'makes range out of today's cells
    Set rng = Range(Cells(1, "A"), Cells(i - 1, ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns.count))


    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

    ...

End Sub

Function RangetoHTML(rng As Range)
    ...
End Function
```

Comment: thanks, however that code came up with a sub or function not defined error in this section of the code: .HTMLBody = RangetoHTML(rng) What would I need to change in order to fix this? Also, does this code you've written completely replace my pre-existing code in VBA?

Comment: @NHure92 I didn't include that function in my answer (that's originally from your question) because I didn't make any changes to it :)

Comment: @NHure92 it would replace your `Mail_Sheet_Outlook_Body` function but you would keep your `RangetoHTML` function

Comment: Okay, I know its a big favour to ask but would you be able to combine the master workbook code you've written with my pre-existing code so I don't lose my original functions? I've tried doing it myself but it has returned errors. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, I've tried it but it says subscript out of range.

Comment: @NHure92 here? `Set ws2 = sheets(ws1.index + 1)`

Comment: @NHure92 It says "adjust as necessary" because I don't know the layout of your document. My assumption was that the 'today' sheet would be just to the right of the 'master' sheet. If they have static names you can just use that instead like `Set ws2 = sheets("sheetName")`

Comment: Okay, I've adjusted it and that part of the code is working now. However in the second sub, it is coming up with Run-time error 13: Type mismatch

Comment: Any solutions for this? Thanks again

Comment: It is within this section of the code: If CDate(Range("A" & i).Value) <> Date Then
            Exit For
        End If
    Next i

Comment: @NHure92 does your sheet have the `Date` column and is it populated with dates?

Comment: I've added two screenshots as answers, hopefully this helps

Comment: Okay, ignoring that error I'm now getting an error titled run-time error 9: Subscript out or range for this section:  Dim lastRow As Long
    lastRow = ws2.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Comment: @NHure92 not sure!